# Cast from '()' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, pubnub

I'm trying to step through an [AnyObject] array from a completion block and cast the items as Strings so that I can then put them in a tableView. However, when I try to append the individual values of the array I get this error: `Cast from '()' to unrelated type 'String' always fails`. Here is the code:

```
client.historyForChannel(ids, start: nil, end: nil, withCompletion: { (result, status) -> Void in

    if status == nil {
        if result!.data.messages.count > 0 {
            let historyMessages = result!.data.messages as? [String]
            for value in historyMessages!{
                self.messagesArray.append(value) as? String //error
            }
        }
    }
})
```

If it helps, I'm using PubNub to create/store messages in my Swift app.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are  you putting `as? String` after the call to append?

Comment: Are you sure that `result!.data.messages` can be cast as a [String]? This might be a good place to use `guard let`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you wrote

```
self.messagesArray.append(value) as? String
```

you probably meant

```
self.messagesArray.append(value as? String)
```

although

```
self.messagesArray.append(value)
```

should suffice because `historyMessages` is already of type `[String]!`.

The error is saying that you are casting the result of `self.messagesArray.append(value)` (which is `Void` because `append` does not return anything) to `String`, which does always fail.

As an aside, your code uses way more exclamation points than it should. You should be using guard-let to make sure your variables are non-nil.

Comment: `historyMessages` is already [String] so it should not be necessary.

Comment: *your code uses way more exclamation points than it should.* — indeed, if your code reads like you're yelling a lot, it's a good sign that you're doing something wrong.